# Proof of Gallai's Theorem for Critical Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A fundamental theorem in Graph theory is the following:

Let $G$ be a $k$-critical graph with $k\geq 4$ and $G\neq K_k$. Then every block in the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices of degree $k-1$ in $G$ is either complete or an odd cycle. Moreover, 
$$2|E(G)| \geq (k-1)|V(G)| + \frac{k-1}{k^2-3} |V(G)|$$

I'm looking for a proof of the above. Does anyone have or know where I can find a proof of it?

Thank you!

Comment: These two papers cite Gallai's original paper and prove better versions of the bound you gave, however I haven't been able to find an online copy of the original paper. [Paper 1](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/v5i1r4/pdf) [Paper 2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98001009)